# Socket.io error: "headers already sent" after update

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, https, socket.io

after updating socket.io from version 1.3.5 to 2.0.1 Im getting error when connecting to server: "headers already sent", but not always, sometimes it works.

I updated also node(4.5.0=>6.10.3) and express(4.14.0=>4.15.3) but i feel it's socket.io problem.

This is my code, it's working on 1.3.5 without problems:

```
var app = require("express")();
var https = require('https');

var server = https.createServer({ 
                key: fs.readFileSync('key.key'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt'),
                ca: fs.readFileSync('Chain-SHA2.crt'),
                requestCert: false,
                rejectUnauthorized: false
             },app);
server.listen(8081);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);



app.post("/xxx", function(request, response) {
    //some code
});

app.listen(8080);



io.on('connection', function(socket){
    //some code
});
```

Comment: I believe the question will benefit from adding a stack trace of the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found up what caused that. And it was not error "headers already sent", it was just loading very long time.

I moved website to new server. I turned off the old server but there was still a lot of people that had website opened in the browser. On new server i updated socket.io to 2.0.1 but users that were still connected were trying to connect to server with socket client version 1.3.5 that was causing something like DDOS, because with older client version it was opening and closing connections instantly. It was like 50 connections per second, so with 50 people it was slowing down server. So i had to change socket port and now everything is ok.

But... My new question is how can I protect sockets against such "attack"?